# Why composer "psr-4" loading not woking in outer folder

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I have this in composer:

```
"MyCompany\\": ["app/MyCompany/", "app/LaravelPackage/src/MyCompany/"]
```

and everything works fine. This also works fine:

```
"MyCompany\\": ["app/MyCompany/", "app/Console/../LaravelPackage/src/MyCompany/"]
```

Even with non existing folder and path back, works:

THIS IS PROBABY BUG. TRY IF YOU DON'T BELIEVE.

```
"MyCompany\\": ["app/MyCompany/", "app/Console-babababa/../LaravelPackage/src/MyCompany/"]
```

But if I move package out of root folder where I run composer install it not works:

```
"MyCompany\\": ["app/MyCompany/", "../app/LaravelPackage/src/MyCompany/"]
```

This should work or ?

Answer (score 0):

- I suppose your `"app/Console-babababa/../LaravelPackage/src/MyCompany/"` case is not a bug but a feature ;)
- About `"../app/LaravelPackage/src/MyCompany/"`, it's probably just how Composer is designed.

You could have a look at this recently implemented way of defining a repository: [Repositories > Hosting your own > Path](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path). Though, it should be considered as a "last pick" solution, as it's very quick to set up but lacks flexibility.

You should consider the other options listed in the [Hosting your own](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) section. For local development, Toran Proxy is very easy to set up and use.